# Access Property Value using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, .net-4.0

I have an object

```
public class School
{
  public Employee Emp{get;set;}
  public string City{get;set;}
}

public class Employee
{
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Using reflection I need to fetch this Employee Name from the school object

I Tried

```
School schl=New School();schl.Employee=new Employee{Name="Shalem"};

var empName= schl.GetType().GetProperty("Emp.Name").GetValue(schl, null)
```

Also tried

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection allProp= TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(schl);

var empName=allProp["Emp.Name"].GetValue(schl);
```

I always get null. How can i get?

Note: The thing is i dont know what object it will contain. But all i know is i will get the exact name with inner object like "Emp.Name" etc. Need a generic solution

Answer (score 2):

```
School schl=New School();
schl.Employee=new Employee{Name="Shalem"};

var emp = schl.GetType().GetProperty("Emp").GetValue(schl, null)
var empName = emp.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(emp, null);
```

Split it up, get the `Employee` object and then get the `Name` of the `Employee`.

Although I don't see the benefit for this in this instance when you can do `string empName = schl.Employee.Name` - unless the scope of the code is different?